# FTP Server written in C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I stumbled accross this site today

http://blogs.msdn.com/joelpob/archive/2004/02/16/74433.aspx

which is a C# command line FTP server, unfortunately the download points to the old gotdotnet site which is now closed ..

Does anybody know where I could find it, or another FTP Server implementation written in C# ?

Thanks

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20060305191700/http://www.gotdotnet.com/Community/UserSamples/Download.aspx?SampleGuid=0A7606F3-F8EC-4E39-8D0E-517248B7164C

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380769/Creating-an-FTP-Server-in-Csharp-with-IPv6-Support

Supports FTPS (FTP over SSL) and IPv6

Answer (score 2):

Personally I recommend active products maintained by nice companies, such as

http://www.remobjects.com/ip.aspx

Comment: I tried it, it does look like a nice library, but it is still at an early stage - and I was expecting to see samples on how to use it, but could not find any ..
the only samples link : http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Internet_Pack_Samples

is a broken link ..

Comment: The samples are bundled in the installer, so after installation you can see samples on how to do FTP servers.