# Send and receive a file using .NET WebClient or related objects

Tags: c#, mono, webclient, file-transfer, httplistener

First of all, I'm completely open to suggestions for alternative strategies, since this is not a space I'm hugely familiar with.

I have what I think is a simple problem.  I have a client app and a server app, and I want to send a bunch of files from the client to the server.  I don't want to require the user to set up file shares or anything, so my thinking was:

1. I'll have an app on the "server" using HttpListener to listen to file transfer requests from the client.
2. I'll have an app on the client using WebClient.UploadFile to initiate the transfers.

Twist: The server is a Mac, and I need to use things that are supported by Mono.  I'm not looking to have the server install ASP.NET / IIS / whatever.  In fact, the less the user has to do, the better. (The user in this case will be in control of both the client and the server, by the way.)

So, short questions:

1. Is there a better/easier way than WebClient/HttpListener to send a bunch of files from one machine on a LAN to another?  TCP-something?  Sockets-something-or-other? (You can see my ignorance.)
2. Assuming I use HTTP, are there more straightforward ways to download files than using an HttpListener and manually parsing the requests to get rid of headers, etc.?

Comment: Maybe `WebClient/WebServiceHost` ? That way you don't have to manage the server site threads...

Comment: Why not [make your Mac an SFTP server](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_make_your_mac_sftp_server)? Then download [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and use its PSFTP program to copy the files. That's going to be much easier than writing, installing, and maintaining a custom application to do the job.

Comment: @JimMischel The problem isn't that I need to send some of my files from a PC to a Mac; I am actually building software for end users who I wouldn't expect to have to set up an FTP server, use putty manually, etc.  In fact, the entire point is that the deployment will happen in one click, with as little user configuration / action as possible.  Requiring that the end user set up an FTP server, etc. kinda defeats the purpose of my "it just works" solution.  The way I envision it, all they'll have to do is install an app on their Mac, and maybe set some *minor* settings.

Comment: And my point is that it *should* be possible to write a script that does the server configuration automatically. Same on the client. And you can easily write a Powershell script, batch file, or simple C# program to drive SFTP. Come to think of it, if you made the Mac a simple FTP server (i.e. not SFTP) then you could use the built-in Windows FTP client. Or, you could find an [FTP Server written in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394620/ftp-server-written-in-c-sharp), and use [System.Net.Ftp.Client](http://netftp.codeplex.com/) in your client code.